# How to get youtube tags using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, youtube, css-selectors

I was able to retrieve all other information that I needed using selenium CSS selector but the video tags. I know I can find the tags if I do the following:

open youtube --> go to a video -->  right-click --> view page source --> control + find --> type 'keywords' --> go to the second result.

Does anyone have an idea of how to get a CSS selector or XPATH to get the video tags? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use chrome [dev](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open) tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you post the code and by analysis we try to adjust what you need. Anyway, to get the XPATH you should locate via HTML the register. Look for the class="style-scope ytd-item-section-renderer" on Youtube. Below that, you might find a list of each video, were the "title" equals the name of the video.

If thats the case, use the CSS from Selenium to locate by your preference!

Comment: Got it sorry. I'll make sure I'll do it when and if I post questions. Thanks